# Overriding JavaScript function throws error "Some modules could not be started" and "web is not defined"

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12

I’m trying to override some javascript functions with my custom module but it does not work and throws me an error inside browser console:

```
error: Some modules could not be started

Failed modules:
"custom_theme.custom_table_rows"

Debug:
"custom_theme.custom_table_rows":
error: ReferenceError: "web is not defined"
```

I have this js file `odoo\addons\custom_theme\static\src\js\views\list\list_renderer.js` which is copy-paste from the source code (with `rows.length` changed from 4 to 1):

```js
odoo.define('custom_theme.custom_table_rows', function (require){
    "use strict";

    //require the module to modify:
    var ListRenderer = require(web.ListRenderer);

    //override the method:
    ListRenderer.include({
        _renderBody: function () {
            var $rows = this._renderRows();
            while ($rows.length < 1) {
                $rows.push(this._renderEmptyRow());
            }
            return $('<tbody>').append($rows);
        }
      });
  });
```

And I called it inside `odoo\addons\custom_theme\views\header.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="Custom_header_theme" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr=".">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/custom_theme/static/src/scss/style.scss"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_theme/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js"/>
                <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_theme/static/src/js/chrome/abstract_web_client.js"/> -->
            </xpath>
    </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Also `header.xml` and the `web` are called inside manifest:

```py
'depends': ['base','web'],

'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
        'views/header.xml',
    ],
```

And it does nothing only throws an error.

When I instead modify the js file directly inside the source code (`odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js`) it is working and changes are applied (less rows are appearing).

My module as a whole is working because it applies custom theme inside `style.scss` (also called inside `header.xml`). I only can't get the custom javascript to work (with different functions as well) while modifing the `web` module.

What is wrong? Why it says that `web` is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require accept the `name` of the `module` that you want to use as a `string`:

```js
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
```

this why you get undefined `web` variable, because there is no `web` variable and you are trying to get `ListRenderer` attribute from it, at least this what your browser think you are doing.